# SwiftUI load data from Firebase to TextView

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have a Swift5 project but i decided that it would be easier to build only one of it's screen with SwiftUI.
The problem is that i don't know anything about SwiftUI so i am sorry if my question is stupid lol.
There is a TextView on the screen and i would like to load the text data from firebase.
My problem is that i can't use the loaded data in the TextView.

Can someone help me how i can use the function's variable in my VStack ( if its even possible )?
I tried putting the function in the VStack but it gave me some error.

Here is my code:

```
 var body: some View {
        List {
            VStack {
                Text("Just some dummy data, this is not important.")
                // i want the "text" variable from loadData() to be in this Text                
            }
        }.onAppear {
            func loadData() {
                guard let userdef = userdefStr(forKey: "didSelect") else { return }

                self.db.collection("news").whereField("title", isEqualTo: userdef)
                    .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                        if let err = err {
                            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                        } else {
                            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {

                               let text = document.data()["text"] as? String ?? ""
                                // this variable should be in the VStack's Text
                                print("text: \(text)")
                                Text(text)
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            // i think this is how i can call the loadData function,maybe i am wrong
            loadData()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for my question is called 'SwiftUI state variables'.

I had to make a new State variable: 
`@State var text = "Just some dummy data, this is not important."`

In the VStack: `Text(text)`

Ad lastly after the `let text = document.data()["text"] as? String ?? ""` i put `self.text = description`

Comment: You will also want to remove `Text(text)` after the `print("text" \(text)") statement.

This is an interesting approach, and definitely feasible. However, I'd recommend extracting your data access layer into a separate class to make your code more maintainable.